# Amazon Web Services - What do i need?

Tags: ios, web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

Sorry for long explanation but I'm trying to find the right moves for days, any help would be much appreciated.

My IOS app will be used daily, An image and some data will be displayed to the user and will be saved not to connect again. So an user will use approximately 30kb per day.

Now, for testing, I'm using a basic hosting plan for MSSQL and Web Service. On SQL Server, I have 4 tables and an average of 5 columns (I mean It's not a complicated database)(and also I have a subquery). And I'm using .net web service for communicating from IOS app. And lastly, one image for one day is hosted.

I've tried to explain basically but It's expected to reach at least 1 million user after a short period of time according to my big clients.

So I want to start with AWS not to fail but really I don't know which products/settings do i need (from few users to millions) and how to start to AWS EC2. Also I want to specify that after AWS's documents and googling, I'm confused.

At least please show me the way. Thanks..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want autoscaling both in the webtier and in database resources. You also likely want high availability (i.e. trans-AZ, trans-regional deployment). This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11623221/877115) might help point you in the right direction. Start with ElasticBeanstalk and RDS (if you can afford it). They both abstract out huge swathes of autoscaling.

Also pay close attention to the [ElasticBeanstalk architectural overview.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11444005/connecting-to-mysql-on-aws-elastic-beanstalk/11471408#11471408) It'll help you distinguish between the web tier of your application, any application layers, and the database layer of your stack.

Comment: Thank you, what is your estimate about initial prices (first 1-2 months)?

Comment: No idea. Fortunately Amazon provides a [monthly cost calculator](http://calculator.s3.amazonaws.com/calc5.html) that should help you get a baseline.

Comment: I didn't understand that calculator very much. When i clicked 'web application' it says $2k but if i enter my own values it says free :)

Comment: One more question, should i really transfer to AWS or any good hosting provider can be enough?

Comment: Depends entirely on how much you want to put into it, how much you want to learn about AWS, and what you think you'll need. It's overkill for many, but if you're in the free tier (it sounds like you might be), it's a decent way to learn.